# Web Page based Winsock

Tags: vb6, html, winsock

Is there a web page based version of vb6's Winsock?
I want a web page to send a message to a vb6 program on a different PC.
Any Examples would be great help, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: You could create a VB6 ActiveX control, but it would be impractical to use due to security lockdown in most IE instalaltions and lack of support in alternative contrarian browsers.

Real answer: You are probably going to look at using some sort of scriptable HTTP Request component (such as XmlHttpRequest) though you must consider *cross-domain request* security even then.  The "VB program on a different PC" would need to be an HTTP server or run under one via classic ASP, as a CGI application, etc.

And of course there would need to be a path from the client web page to the server (i.e. you have firewall and NAT issues to address) in any case.